# You can now view XYZ in the browser, how to change the project name?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I cloned a React project from github, and modified something in it. Then i run it with `npm start`.

I noticed that after run in console it shows me the original project name of the github that i cloned from which is **XYZ**:

```
Compiled successfully!

You can now view XYZ in the browser.  

  Local:            http://localhost:3000   
  On Your Network:  http://192.168.1.12:3000

Note that the development build is not optimized.
To create a production build, use npm run build.
```

How to change this name (**XYZ**) to a custom one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **package.json** file of the cloned project, you will find that name , just change it to the desired one.
The name must be all lowercased and there no space between.

Example:

```
{
  "name": "newname",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    //...
  }
```